# Cocoon - Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) for look-up or create :belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, cocoon-gem

Following the Cocoon wiki for implementing [The look-up or create :belongs_to](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms#the-look-up-or-create-belongs_to) I'm receiving the error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`. I'm not exactly sure what its referring to being that I'm following the tutorial verbatim aside from using slim as my precompiler. Here's what my code looks like:

**Models**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :tasks
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

**Projects Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <h3>Tasks</h3>
  <div id="tasks">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
      <%= render 'task_fields', :f => task %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :tasks %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="user">
    <div id="user_from_list">
      <%= f.association :user, collection: User.all(:order => 'name'),  :prompt => 'Choose an existing user' %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add a new person as owner', f, :user %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Projects Controller**

```
 ...

 def project_params
   params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, tasks_attributes: [:id, :description, :done, :_destroy], user_attributes: [:id, :name])
 end
```

**Backtrace**

```
app/views/projects/_form.html.erb:16:in `block in _app_views_projects__form_html_erb___3132123068035883478_70337216288160'
app/views/projects/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_projects__form_html_erb___3132123068035883478_70337216288160'
app/views/projects/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_projects_new_html_erb__2418839848133678570_70337176808940'
```

Comment: @BroiSatse Updated my question to include the backtrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveRecord#all` has been changed in rails 4 - this is now doing what `scoped` used to do. It does not expect any extra params. Instead of `User.all(order: 'name')` do:

```
User.order(:name)
```

Comment: Thanks. It would definitely help if they updated their wiki to mention this.

Comment: I noticed that when I select a user from the dropdown its not being saved. Judging by the code in the question woul you happen to know why that is?

Comment: Check the logs for paremters being send and comare those with your strong_params. I think you need to permit `user_id` as well, but check it first.